# Function on scroll doesnt work on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first one on mobile works like a charm, but in desktop doesnt work. Why?

My target its just, remove the class on scroll.

```
$('#page').on({'touchmove': function(e) { 
        $('#menu-mega-menu ul.sub-menu.toggled-on').removeClass('toggled-on');
        $('#menu-mega-menu li.mega-menu.sfHover').removeClass('sfHover');
    }
});

    var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    if (scroll > position) {
        $('#menu-mega-menu ul.sub-menu.toggled-on').removeClass('toggled-on');
    $('#menu-mega-menu li.mega-menu.sfHover').removeClass('sfHover');
    }
});
```

I tried:

```
$('window').on({'scroll': function() { 
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >  1) {
        $('#menu-mega-menu ul.sub-menu.toggled-on').removeClass('toggled-on');
    $('#menu-mega-menu li.mega-menu.sfHover').removeClass('sfHover');
    }
}
});
```

without luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$('window')` you need to write `$(window)` without quotes.
Example:

```
var position = $(window).scrollTop();
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > position) {
        $('.test').removeClass('test');
    }
});
```